# O que fazer para que quando o usuário passe o cursor sobre uma imagem, ela se amplie um pouco? ( de preferência usando somente HTML e CSS)

Tags: html, css

Eu queria que quando o usuário passasse o cursor sobre determinada imagem, a imagem ampliasse um pouco, e somente isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É bem simples, você só precisa realmente de `CSS`. Segue um exemplo:

```css
.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

```html
<img class="grow" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png" />
```

No trecho de código acima a propriedade CSS `transition` tem em seu valor o item `.2s` representando o tempo do efeito de aumento de tamanho. Para deixar mais demorado basta aumenta esse número.
Na linha seguinte temos o estilo aplicado ao passar o mouse por cima, o gatilho `:hover`. Nele informamos o valor da propriedade CSS `transform` com a escala `1.1`. Caso queira um aumento de tamanho ainda maior, pode alterar seu valor para 1.2, 1.3 e etc.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Vou tentar! :)

Answer (score 5):

Segue o exemplo

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

img:hover{
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://file.iviewui.com/dist/76ecb6e76d2c438065f90cd7f8fa7371.png">
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: Neste caso é melhor utilizar o transform: scale, porque assim a imagem ira sera ampliada do centro para as laterais.

Usando width ela amplia da lateral esquerda para a direita e para baixo.

Comment: @MaurícioJúnior Na verdade depende do que ele precisa, tem casos que eu uso o `width` e casos que uso o `transform: scale`. Isso varia bastante da necessidade